# How to achieve HBase Prefix Filter on "column Qualifier"

Tags: apache-phoenix

How can I achieve HBase Prefix Filter on "column Qualifier" using Phoenix.
My column Qualifier is like D_com.google    D_com.mail.yahoo  ..etc so I want to search all column Qualifier who start with D_ prefix

Thanks,
Manjeet Singh